# WPF C#: Rearrange items in listbox via drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am trying to figure out how to move the items in a pre-populated listbox up and down via mouse drags.

I have looked at the Control.DoDragDrop method from microsoft's api, but I still can't get it to do anything.

I would appreciate any help since I am new to the visual studios environment.

Comment: https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop This is a lifesaver and the example is pretty clear

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I've tried creating one using ObservableCollection. Have a look.

```
    ObservableCollection<Emp> _empList = new ObservableCollection<Emp>();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _empList .Add(new Emp("1", 22));
        _empList .Add(new Emp("2", 18));
        _empList .Add(new Emp("3", 29));
        _empList .Add(new Emp("4", 9));
        _empList .Add(new Emp("5", 29));
        _empList .Add(new Emp("6", 9));
        listbox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        listbox1.ItemsSource = _empList;
        
        Style itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, true));
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(listbox1_Drop)));
        listbox1.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
    }
```

Drag and drop process:

```
    void s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is ListBoxItem)
        {
            ListBoxItem draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
            draggedItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    void listbox1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Emp droppedData = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Emp)) as Emp;
        Emp target = ((ListBoxItem)(sender)).DataContext as Emp;

        int removedIdx = listbox1.Items.IndexOf(droppedData);
        int targetIdx = listbox1.Items.IndexOf(target);

        if (removedIdx < targetIdx)
        {
            _empList.Insert(targetIdx + 1, droppedData);
            _empList.RemoveAt(removedIdx);
        }
        else
        {
            int remIdx = removedIdx+1;
            if (_empList.Count + 1 > remIdx)
            {
                _empList.Insert(targetIdx, droppedData);
                _empList.RemoveAt(remIdx);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:

- One thing that sucks in this implementation is that since it uses the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event, the dragged item does not look like a selected item.
- And also for an easier implementation, the drop target is the list box items and not the listbox itself - might need a better solution for this.

Comment: If you change PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown to PreviewMouseMoveEvent, and then add e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed to your if statement, you fix the selection issue.

Comment: I needed to add `listbox1.Items.Refresh();` to the end of the Drop handler, but other than, it works great!

Comment: @Andrew, do you use observablecollection? if you use it, it should be auto update

Comment: You are correct, in the process of changing the class, I changed the collection to a List without thinking about it.  However, I have a button that changes the evaluation of the `.ToString()` method for the selected item.  I did still need `listbox1.Items.Refresh();` to refresh the text.

Comment: This works -- thanks.  But why doesn't it work replacing the code (that sets the ItemContainerStyle) with the respective XAML tags -- AllowDrop="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Drop="listbox1_Drop" -- ?

Comment: @IronRod - Figured this out -- see additional answer

Comment: I know this is a little late in the game, but how did you initialize listbox1 in the code behind? this is my current hangup in my code.

Comment: @tCoe - what do you mean by initialize? you can do a ListBox listbox1 = new ListBox(), but you can do it in xaml

Comment: @dnr3 I am trying to implement the code above in WPF using MVVM Lite. So i had to make adjustments here and there, but mainly having trouble binding the listbox_1Drop to the listbox view

Comment: @tCoe - do you mean you want to subscribe the drop event in the xaml instead of code behind? check the answer from IronRod on how to do that below. But if you're thinking of no code behind at all then I think you'll have to make it as a behavior or something.

Comment: @dnr3 I have a dynamically created collection in the VM that populates on load. This would be the _empList in your example. If i were to put the above code in the code-behind how do i bind to that list, or connect to that list once its populated in the view?

Comment: I keep getting the error "No Overload for s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown matches delegate MouseEventHandler

Comment: @tCoe assigning collection to a listbox is by simply put assigned it to the itemssource property (listbox1.ItemsSource = _empList;). about the error, I think you're using a worng event, on my code I use the  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent which is a MouseButtonEventHandler and not MouseEventHandler

Comment: You could use `ObservableCollection.Move` instead of `InsertAt` and `RemoveAt`

Answer (score 34):

Using dnr3's answers I have created version with fixed selection issues.

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxReorderDemo.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListBoxReorderDemo" Height="300" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ListBoxReorderDemo
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Item(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private Point _dragStartPoint;

        private T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parentObject == null)
                return null;
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
        }

        private IList<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _items.Add(new Item("1"));
            _items.Add(new Item("2"));
            _items.Add(new Item("3"));
            _items.Add(new Item("4"));
            _items.Add(new Item("5"));
            _items.Add(new Item("6"));

            listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            listBox.ItemsSource = _items;

            listBox.PreviewMouseMove += ListBox_PreviewMouseMove;

            var style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, true));
            style.Setters.Add(
                new EventSetter(
                    ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                    new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
            style.Setters.Add(
                    new EventSetter(
                        ListBoxItem.DropEvent, 
                        new DragEventHandler(ListBoxItem_Drop)));
            listBox.ItemContainerStyle = style;
        }

        private void ListBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = _dragStartPoint - point;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                    Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
            {
                var lb = sender as ListBox;
                var lbi = FindVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource));
                if (lbi != null)
                {
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbi, lbi.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _dragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ListBoxItem)
            {
                var source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Item)) as Item;
                var target = ((ListBoxItem)(sender)).DataContext as Item;

                int sourceIndex = listBox.Items.IndexOf(source);
                int targetIndex = listBox.Items.IndexOf(target);

                Move(source, sourceIndex, targetIndex);
            }
        }

        private void Move(Item source, int sourceIndex, int targetIndex)
        {
            if (sourceIndex < targetIndex)
            {
                _items.Insert(targetIndex + 1, source);
                _items.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                int removeIndex = sourceIndex + 1;
                if (_items.Count + 1 > removeIndex)
                {
                    _items.Insert(targetIndex, source);
                    _items.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version with support for generics and data binding.

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxReorderDemo.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxReorderDemo"
        Title="ListBoxReorderDemo" Height="300" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <local:ItemDragAndDropListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </local:ItemDragAndDropListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ListBoxReorderDemo
{
    public class DragAndDropListBox<T> : ListBox 
        where T : class
    {
        private Point _dragStartPoint;

        private P FindVisualParent<P>(DependencyObject child) 
            where P : DependencyObject
        {
            var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parentObject == null)
                return null;

            P parent = parentObject as P;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;

            return FindVisualParent<P>(parentObject);
        }

        public DragAndDropListBox()
        {
            this.PreviewMouseMove += ListBox_PreviewMouseMove;

            var style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));

            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, true));

            style.Setters.Add(
                new EventSetter(
                    ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                    new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));

            style.Setters.Add(
                    new EventSetter(
                        ListBoxItem.DropEvent, 
                        new DragEventHandler(ListBoxItem_Drop)));

            this.ItemContainerStyle = style;
        }

        private void ListBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = _dragStartPoint - point;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                    Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
            {
                var lb = sender as ListBox;
                var lbi = FindVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource));
                if (lbi != null)
                {
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbi, lbi.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _dragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ListBoxItem)
            {
                var source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(T)) as T;
                var target = ((ListBoxItem)(sender)).DataContext as T;

                int sourceIndex = this.Items.IndexOf(source);
                int targetIndex = this.Items.IndexOf(target);

                Move(source, sourceIndex, targetIndex);
            }
        }

        private void Move(T source, int sourceIndex, int targetIndex)
        {
            if (sourceIndex < targetIndex)
            {
                var items = this.DataContext as IList<T>;
                if (items != null)
                {
                    items.Insert(targetIndex + 1, source);
                    items.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var items = this.DataContext as IList<T>;
                if (items != null)
                {
                    int removeIndex = sourceIndex + 1;
                    if (items.Count + 1 > removeIndex)
                    {
                        items.Insert(targetIndex, source);
                        items.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Item(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class ItemDragAndDropListBox : DragAndDropListBox<Item> { }

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private IList<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _items.Add(new Item("1"));
            _items.Add(new Item("2"));
            _items.Add(new Item("3"));
            _items.Add(new Item("4"));
            _items.Add(new Item("5"));
            _items.Add(new Item("6"));

            listBox.DataContext = _items;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very nice indeed, thanks to you and @dnr3.  The only thing I could see that could improve it is if the cursor, when dragged, could hover over the part of the listbox that has no files.  As it is, the cursor changes to a null set, no-drag symbol if you drag too low.  And I suppose if you could drag multiple items.  Not that I'm complaining, this is more than enough to get started.

Comment: I had a small issue with this solution, because you store the drag position when the mouse button is clicked, but you search the item in the mouse move. This means that in some cases the item you find in the mouse move event is different than the actual clicked item if you click on the edge of an item. I changed to logic to search the clicked item in the mouse down event and store it in a variable and in the mouse move event I used the previously stored clicked item to prevent this edge case

Answer (score 17):

I would suggest using the drag and drop behavior called [GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop). It allows MVVM style use cases using attached property setters to enable it, no need for code behind in your views. You should check out the link for a simple example.

Comment: While I generally don't like adding libraries for such a narrow use-case (drag and drop) the one you've linked to appears to be very well thought out and complete. At the same time, the amount of code for proper drag & drop is surprisingly large if one wants a decent, complete implementation. I actually might make an exception and use the library you've linked to. Thanks!

Comment: This library is really nice! I'd recommend this to anyone needing to use drag-and-drop for anything more complicated than the basics, and even then.

Comment: great library very simple

Comment: @rawpower I agree that this library is great, and I'd like to add I very much prefer adding a library with a narrow use-case over libraries that try to fix or enhance everything. That only works if you use _only one_ library, but try DevExpress together with Telerik and Infragistics and Prism for example...

Comment: using this library, i getting visual bug... hove any ideas to fix it? i create the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118372/reordering-listbox-elements-with-gong-wpf-dragdrop-causes-visual-bugs

Answer (score 8):

I took dnr3's answer and altered it for implementation in XAML.  Same result, just prefer doing what I can in XAML rather than in the code-behind.

In place of the code-behind:

```
Style itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AllowDropProperty, true));
itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(listbox1_Drop)));
listbox1.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
```

Put this in the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxDragDrop" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="s_PreviewMouseMoveEvent"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="listbox1_Drop"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxDragDrop}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224"/>
</Grid>
```

This is mouse-handler placed in the code-behind of the XAML.

```
void s_PreviewMouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBoxItem && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        ListBoxItem draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
        draggedItem.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what your Handler looks like for the Mouse Button Event handler?

Answer (score 3):

Repair code :

```
private void listbox1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBoxItem)
    {
        Emp droppedData = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Emp)) as Emp;
        Emp target = ((ListBoxItem)(sender)).DataContext as Emp;

        int removedIdx = listbox1.Items.IndexOf(droppedData);
        int targetIdx = listbox1.Items.IndexOf(target);

        if (removedIdx < targetIdx)
        {
            _empList.Insert(targetIdx + 1, droppedData);
            _empList.RemoveAt(removedIdx);
        }
        else
        {
            int remIdx = removedIdx + 1;
            if (_empList.Count + 1 > remIdx)
            {
                _empList.Insert(targetIdx, droppedData);
                _empList.RemoveAt(remIdx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has helped me greatly thank you. Especially the generics version.

I made the following amendments:

Because I don't set the DataContext of the ListBox (just the ItemsSource), I use

```
var items = this.ItemsSource as IList<T>;
```

in the Move method.

And at the end of "Move" I added:

```
this.SelectedItem = source;
```

as I want the user to have the moved item as the current selection.

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon **Wiesław Šoltés**'s modification of **dnr3**'s answer, I abstracted this out into an easily-reusable class, so that you can set up multiple of these lists with only a few lines of code. I also added a feature whereby each item alternates between 2 background colours, for easier viewing (though this feature can easily be removed, if you don't want it).

F.Y.I: Sorry if you're a lover of 'var', but I am absolutely not and those got removed by my IDE, and I don't intend to put them back. Of course this changes nothing about the actual program behaviour and should improve compile-time anyway, so.. winning! :p

Here is the class:

```
/// <typeparam name="IT">The item type to be stored in this list</typeparam>
internal class ReorderableList<IT> where IT : class
{
    private readonly SolidColorBrush m_alternator1, m_alternator2; // Background colours for the list items to alternate between
    private readonly ListBox m_ListBox; // The target ListBox we're modifying
    private readonly string m_displayMemberPath; // The name of the member in to display 
    private readonly IList<IT> m_items = new ObservableCollection<IT>();
    private Point m_cursorStartPos;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the list (this must be done after components are initialized and loaded!).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resourceProvider">Pass 'this' for this parameter</param>
    /// <param name="listBox">The target ListBox control to modify</param>
    /// <param name="displayMemberPath">The name of the member in the generic type contained in this list, to be displayed</param>
    public ReorderableList(ListBox listBox, string displayMemberPath, SolidColorBrush alternator1, SolidColorBrush alternator2)
    {
        m_ListBox = listBox;
        m_displayMemberPath = displayMemberPath;
        m_alternator1 = alternator1;
        m_alternator2 = alternator2;

        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Set the list box's items source and tell it what member in the IT class to use for the display name
        // Add an event handler for preview mouse move

        m_ListBox.DisplayMemberPath = m_displayMemberPath;
        m_ListBox.ItemsSource = m_items;
        m_ListBox.PreviewMouseMove += OnListPreviewMouseMove;

        // Create the item container style to be used by the listbox
        // Add mouse event handlers to the style

        Style style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(UIElement.AllowDropProperty, true));
        style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnListPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
        style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(UIElement.DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(OnListDrop)));

        // Add triggers to alternate the background colour of each element based on its alternation index
        // (Remove this, as well as the two SolidColorBrush resources if you don't want this feature)

        Trigger trigger1 = new Trigger()
        {
            Property = ItemsControl.AlternationIndexProperty,
            Value = 0
        };

        Setter setter1 = new Setter()
        {
            Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
            Value = m_alternator1
        };

        trigger1.Setters.Add(setter1);
        style.Triggers.Add(trigger1);

        Trigger trigger2 = new Trigger()
        {
            Property = ItemsControl.AlternationIndexProperty,
            Value = 1
        };

        Setter setter2 = new Setter()
        {
            Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
            Value = m_alternator2
        };

        trigger2.Setters.Add(setter2);
        style.Triggers.Add(trigger2);

        // Set the item container style

        m_ListBox.ItemContainerStyle = style;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the list. If [ignoreDuplicates] is false and the item is already in the list,
    /// the item won't be added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to add</param>
    /// <param name="ignoreDuplicates">Whether or not to add the item regardless of whether it's already in the list</param>
    /// <returns>Whether or not the item was added</returns>
    public bool Add(IT item, bool ignoreDuplicates = true)
    {
        if (!ignoreDuplicates && Contains(item)) return false;

        m_items.Add(item);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes an item from the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to remove</param>
    /// <returns>Whether or not the item was removed from the list. This will be false if the item was not in the list to begin with.</returns>
    public bool Remove(IT item)
    {
        if (Contains(item)) return false;

        m_items.Remove(item);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether or not the list contains the given item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to check for</param>
    /// <returns>Whether or not the list contains the given item.</returns>
    public bool Contains(IT item)
    {
        return m_items.Contains(item);
    }

    private void OnListPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        m_cursorStartPos = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void OnListPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentCursorPos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector cursorVector = m_cursorStartPos - currentCursorPos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed
            &&(Math.Abs(cursorVector.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance
            || Math.Abs(cursorVector.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
        {
            ListBoxItem targetItem = FindVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource));
            if (targetItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(targetItem, targetItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnListDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListBoxItem item)
        {
            IT source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(IT)) as IT;
            IT target = item.DataContext as IT;

            int sourceIndex = m_ListBox.Items.IndexOf(source);
            int targetIndex = m_ListBox.Items.IndexOf(target);

            Move(source, sourceIndex, targetIndex);
        }
    }

    private void Move(IT source, int sourceIndex, int targetIndex)
    {
        if (sourceIndex < targetIndex)
        {
            m_items.Insert(targetIndex + 1, source);
            m_items.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            int removeIndex = sourceIndex + 1;
            if (m_items.Count + 1 > removeIndex)
            {
                m_items.Insert(targetIndex, source);
                m_items.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    private T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parentObject == null) return null;
        if (parentObject is T parent) return parent;

        return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

And here is an example IT (item type) class (same as in the original answer):

```
public class ExampleItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ExampleItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And finally, the usage:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ReorderableList<ExampleItem> ExampleList;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ExampleList = new ReorderableList<ExampleItem>(myXamlListBoxControl, "Name",
            FindResource("AlternatingBG1") as SolidColorBrush,
            FindResource("AlternatingBG2") as SolidColorBrush);

        ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem("Test Item 1"));
        ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem("Test Item 2"));
        ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem("Test Item 3"));
        ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem("Test Item 4"));
        ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem("Test Item 5"));
        ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem("Test Item 6"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more effort from my side.

Here is the solution which does the following:

- **Maintains the selected item state (in case the ItemsSource is `ObservableCollection`).**
- **Scrolls the list while dragging.**
- **Allows to specify the scrolling intensiveness.**
- **Allows to specify the scrolling area height.**
- **Implemented as behavior, so can be attached to any `ItemsControl`.**

One disadvantage - it works only if `ItemsSource` property is in use. But, I believe, it covers most of the scenarios.

Code:

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyNamespace.Behaviors;

public sealed class DragAndDropRearrangeBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>
{
    #region Dependency properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollOffsetProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ScrollOffset),
                                      typeof(double),
                                      typeof(DragAndDropRearrangeBehavior),
                                      new(5d));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrolAreaHeightProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ScrolAreaHeight),
                                      typeof(double),
                                      typeof(DragAndDropRearrangeBehavior),
                                      new(60d));
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private DependencyPropertyDescriptor? _itemsSourcePorpertyDescriptor;

    private Style? _oldItemContainerStyle;
    private MethodInfo? _moveMethod;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public double ScrollOffset
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScrollOffsetProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScrollOffsetProperty, value);
    }

    public double ScrolAreaHeight
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScrolAreaHeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScrolAreaHeightProperty, value);
    }

    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(_moveMethod))]
    private bool IsMoveMethodAvailable { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Protected methods
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnItemControlLoaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewDragOver -= OnItemsControlDragOver;
        _itemsSourcePorpertyDescriptor?.RemoveValueChanged(AssociatedObject, OnItemsControlItemsSourceChanged);
        _itemsSourcePorpertyDescriptor = null;

        AssociatedObject.ItemContainerStyle = _oldItemContainerStyle;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private methods
    private void OnItemControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.ItemsSource is null)
            return;

        _oldItemContainerStyle = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerStyle;

        var newItemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(FrameworkElement), AssociatedObject.ItemContainerStyle);

        newItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(UIElement.AllowDropProperty, true));
        newItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(UIElement.PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnItemMouseMove)));
        newItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(UIElement.DragOverEvent, new DragEventHandler(OnItemDrag)));

        AssociatedObject.ItemContainerStyle = newItemContainerStyle;

        AssociatedObject.PreviewDragOver += OnItemsControlDragOver;

        _itemsSourcePorpertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, AssociatedObject.GetType());
        _itemsSourcePorpertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, OnItemsControlItemsSourceChanged);

        OnItemsControlItemsSourceChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);

        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnItemControlLoaded;
    }

    // When `ItemsSource` property is changed - we need to check whether we
    // can use the `Move` method or not.
    private void OnItemsControlItemsSourceChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _moveMethod = GetMoveMethod(AssociatedObject.ItemsSource);

        IsMoveMethodAvailable = _moveMethod is not null;
    }

    // Performs scrolling while dragging.
    private void OnItemsControlDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        static bool IsUpScroll(double verticalPosition, double scrollAreaHeight)
            => verticalPosition < scrollAreaHeight;

        static void ScrollUp(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, double offset)
            => scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - offset);

        static bool IsDownScroll(double scrollViewerParentHeight, double verticalPosition, double scrollAreaHeight)
            => verticalPosition > scrollViewerParentHeight - scrollAreaHeight;

        static void ScrollDown(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, double offset)
            => scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + offset);

        if (sender is not ItemsControl itemsControl)
            return;

        var scrollViewer = itemsControl.GetFirstChildOfType<ScrollViewer>();

        if (scrollViewer is null)
            return;

        var verticalPosition = e.GetPosition(itemsControl).Y;

        if (IsUpScroll(verticalPosition, ScrolAreaHeight))
            ScrollUp(scrollViewer, ScrollOffset);
        else if (IsDownScroll(itemsControl.ActualHeight, verticalPosition, ScrolAreaHeight))
            ScrollDown(scrollViewer, ScrollOffset);
    }

    private void OnItemDrag(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.ItemsSource is not IList items)
            return;

        var draggedData = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
        var hoveredData = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;

        RearrangeItems(items, draggedData, hoveredData);
    }

    private void OnItemMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton is not MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            return;

        if (sender is not FrameworkElement draggedItem)
            return;

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, draggedItem.DataContext), DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    // Performs the rearrangement of the items, whether my `Move` method or
    // `Insert` + `Remove`.
    private void RearrangeItems(IList list, object draggedData, object hoveredData)
    {
        if (IsMoveMethodAvailable)
        {
            if (draggedData == hoveredData)
                return;

            var draggedDataIndex = list.IndexOf(draggedData);
            var hoveredDataIndex = list.IndexOf(hoveredData);

            if (draggedDataIndex is not -1 && hoveredDataIndex is not -1)
                _moveMethod.Invoke(AssociatedObject.ItemsSource, [draggedDataIndex, hoveredDataIndex]);
        }
        else
        {
            var draggedDataIndex = list.IndexOf(draggedData);
            var hoveredDataIndex = list.IndexOf(hoveredData);

            if (draggedDataIndex < hoveredDataIndex)
            {
                list.Insert(hoveredDataIndex + 1, draggedData);
                list.RemoveAt(draggedDataIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                draggedDataIndex++;

                if (list.Count + 1 > draggedDataIndex)
                {
                    list.Insert(hoveredDataIndex, draggedData);
                    list.RemoveAt(draggedDataIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This method is required to maintain the item's selection state while dragging.
    private static MethodInfo? GetMoveMethod(IEnumerable list)
    {
        var listType = list.GetType();
        var integerType = typeof(int);

        var methodName = nameof(ObservableCollection<object>.Move);

        return listType.GetMethod(methodName, [integerType, integerType]);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Also - some extension methods which were used in the solution:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyNamespace.Extensions;

internal static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    #region Public methods
    public static T? GetFirstParentOfType<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

        return parent is null
            ? null
            : parent is T castedParent
            ? castedParent
            : GetFirstParentOfType<T>(parent);
    }

    public static DependencyObject? GetFirstParentOfType(this DependencyObject child, Type parentType)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

        return parent is null
            ? null
            : parent.GetType() == parentType
            ? parent
            : GetFirstParentOfType(parent, parentType);
    }

    public static T? GetFirstChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, 0);

        return child is null
            ? null
            : child is T castedChild
            ? castedChild
            : GetFirstChildOfType<T>(child);
    }

    public static DependencyObject? GetFirstChildOfType(this DependencyObject parent, Type childType)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, 0);

        return child is null
            ? null
            : child.GetType() == childType
            ? child
            : GetFirstChildOfType(child, childType);
    }
    #endregion
}
```