# Re Arrange ListBox Items in WPF( Like windows 8 start screen tiles )

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

How can I re arrange list box items like windows 8 start page. I created a sample that is capable of drag and drop / re arrange items inside it. But I don't know how to implement that effect like windows 8 start screen (Like Dragging the item along with the mouse and drop it). In my current implementation, while clicking and dragging a small box along with the curser is coming, that entire item is not coming. How I can implement this in WPF. I am not asking like "Do it for me". Anyone please guide me to implement the same

NB : I creating this in a touch environment

My current implementation is based on the Answer given in the below link
[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Gong-WPF drag and drop library: on GitHub at https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop

There are examples of how to use drag and drop in WPF within the repo there.