# RadListBox vs RadListBoxItem DragDrop WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm working on a `WPF` application with `MVVM` pattern using `Telerik` controls.

I'm using `telerik:RadListBox` for which a collection is bind. My question is when a collection is bound to a RadListBox the collection will be turned as `RadListBox` or `RadListBoxItem` ?

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="lstMarketSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding MarketSeriesCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DraggableListBoxItem}"DragLeave="lstMarketSeries_DragLeave" Style="{StaticResource myListboxStyle}" SelectionMode="Extended" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8">
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

XAML.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Event fired when series are dragged and moved.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void lstMarketSeries_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

   if (sender is RadListBox) // True
    {

    }

   if(sender is RadListBoxItem) //False Why??
    {

    }
}
```

When a collection is bound it should be returning as Items Correct? Why am i getting it as `RadListBox` itself and not `RadListBoxItem` ?

Now i need that Draggable object as `RadListBoxItem`. Is there any way?

FYI,

See here [ListBoxDragDrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop) the sender is `ListBoxItem` and not `ListBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx).

sender is

> The object where the event handler is attached.

That's it.

You are dragging an item, but the event is attached to the container.

```
<telerik:RadListBox ... DragLeave="lstMarketSeries_DragLeave" ... >`
```

Therfore when `DragLeave` event occurs to the RadListBox, the specified handler is fired (which is actually set by you). `sender` is set to be the `RadListBox` because the handler is attached to it, not the item.

You have misunderstood the example you're referring to. Read the code of the example carefully. In the example event handler is set to the `ItemContainerStyle` , [which is used to inflate every item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx). In the example we see the handler, attached to each item individually, therefore `sender` of the handler is set to be an item rather than the control itself.

If you need `sender` to de an item you have to do the same - create a style and attach a handler to it.

Comment: Am i dragging the `RadListBox` or `RadListBoxItem` ?

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop

Comment: @SanthoshKumar i see now whats confusing you. See the updated answer.

Comment: I'm clear now. But what i drag is a `RadListBox` or `RadListBoxItem`? If it is a `RadListBox` how can i change it to `RadListBoxItem` and fire that event?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar the same way as your example shows. Create an ItemContainerStyle and attach the handler to it instead of the box. I have no access to the telerik library now so i cant provide an exact code unfortunately.