# How do I create a dynamic context menu for ListBoxItems?

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I have a style that doesn't seem to be working. In spite of Snoop telling me the `DataContext` for the `ListBoxItem` is correct, nothing shows up. If it was a problem with the binding for `Commands` I would expect to see an empty context menu appear.

The style:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="CommandsContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu>

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CommandsContextMenu}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Binding Path="DataContext.HasCommands" />
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The snoop DataContext:

[image: SnoopDataContext]

The snoop properties showing the ContextMenu property isn't even set.

[image: SnoopProperties]

The idea here, was that without knowing any of the types, I could have a listbox item style where if the thing it was bound to has a property called HasCommands, and it was set to true, then it would set a context menu on that listbox item, bound to the Commands property.

I'm not getting any binding errors or warnings from `PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource`

Why doesn't the context menu get set?

Comment: Oh, wait -- I'm sorry, I just skimmed your question. I think the only problem you may have here is simply where the menu item style is defined. It's in the content, where it'll be ignored. Try putting it in `<ContextMenu><ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle><Style TargetType="MenuItem" .../> ...`

Comment: Context menus are not connected to the visual tree of their "parent".  That means they don't inherit the `DataContext`.  See this question for a few ways to work around it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu

Comment: One potential problem that I see here is that your `ContextMenu` is defined as a resource. By default, only one instance is created and then returned upon every fetch from the dictionary, resulting in this single instance being set as the context menu of multiple elements, which I think might be the cause of your problems. Try setting `x:Shared="False"` on it in order to ensure a new instance is created every time the resource is fetched from the dictionary. Also, @BradleyUffner comment is useful and probably it'll be the next problem you'll encounter.

Comment: all the comments seem to me to be things that would prevent the menu(s) from having items, or from having distinct items, not things that would prevent a context menu from ever being set for any of them. However, I'll give them a try

Comment: @EdPlunkett I thought that one was going to work, it did not =(

Comment: @Maslow try defining the listboxitem style in ListBox.Resources

Comment: @Grx70 that gave me a System.Window.Markup.XamlParseException that shared attribute in namespace ... can only be used in compiled resource dictionaries . and yes I'm aware of the context menu visual parent problem.

Comment: when I stopped using my custom listbox, the context menu worked, but it works better with @EdPlunkett 's suggestion to `<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, that the problem was using something that inherited from `ListBox`

for reference here's my defined class:

```
// adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop
// which was probably adapted from http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html
type DragDropListBox() as self =
    inherit ListBox()
```

which from there only hooks the following

- self.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp
- self.PreviewMouseMove
- override x.OnItemsSourceChanged

and in the intialization it **overwrites the ItemContainerStyle** as follows:

So it turns out, that the problem was using something that inherited from `ListBox`

for reference here's the top of my class:

```
// adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop
// which was probably adapted from http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html
type DragDropListBox() as self =
    inherit ListBox()
```

which from there only hooks the following

- self.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp
- self.PreviewMouseMove
- override x.OnItemsSourceChanged

and in the intialization it **overwrites the ItemContainerStyle** as follows:

```
do
    self.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp.Add listBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp
    //self.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown.Add listBoxPreviewMouseMove //.AddHandler (MouseButtonEventHandler previewMouseMove)
    self.PreviewMouseMove.Add listBoxPreviewMouseMove
    let style =
        let s = Style(typeof<ListBoxItem>)
        s.Setters.Add (Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, true))
        s.Setters.Add (EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, MouseButtonEventHandler listBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown))
        s.Setters.Add (EventSetter(ListBoxItem.DropEvent, DragEventHandler listBoxItemDrop))

        s
    self.ItemContainerStyle <- style
```

now I've got to figure out if you can add two styles together.