# WPF MVVM C#: listbox drag and drop without code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to figure out how to reorder the listbox without any code behind. I tried following this post: [WPF C#: Rearrange items in listbox via drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop) It definitely works, but I want to do it with ICommand or AttachBehavior.

Any suggestion? 
How to hook the Drop and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent with AttachBehavior?

The Listbox's ItemsSource is a Observable Collection.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Where do I re-arrange the observable collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22855/ListBox-Drag-Drop-using-Attached-Properties) CodeProject article. This implementation rely on two attached properties `DragEnabled` and `DropEnabled`.

```
<ListBox lib:DragAndDrop.DragEnabled="true"/> // Source
<ListBox lib:DragAndDrop.DropEnabled="true"/> // Target
```

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for. I want to reorder the items within one listbox. And this project is dragging item from one listbox to another.

Comment: Do you have any other example without finding ancestor?

Comment: If you can also use a ListView then this [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView) articel may help you. This is what I'm using for drag and drop ordering in a ListView. A combination of both is probably what you're searching for.