# WPF list Drag and Drop items with guides (within same list)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

I'm struggling to find clear and meaningful information on WPF and all the decent examples I find for what I want are in WinForms. Within a .NET 5 WPF application I've implemented dragging files from the file system into the application and display the filenames, for specific allowed extensions. I now want to add the ability to click and drag items with the list to re-order them (I hate having up and down buttons alongside the listbox). I would also like to display a red line between the items as a guide for where the item will be inserted when the mouse button is released. Can anyone suggest a pre-made preferably free library that provides a control that already does that OR point me to some current examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop does this answer your question?

Comment: Yep that's great. Specifically it points to gong WPF.DragDrop which is pre-packaged and does everything I'm after. Thanks so much